# Limit the results of a Swift array filter to X for performance

Tags: ios, swift, nspredicate

I have about 2000 elements in my array, and when it is filtered, I would like to end the filtering as soon as I have 5 elements in my filtered array.

Currently it is:

```
providerArray.filter({($0.lowercased().range(of:((row.value as? String)?.lowercased())!) != nil)})
```

which can return up to 2000 results which is a waste of processing, and time.

To be more clear, I need a solution that is equivalent to limiting the filter results like I can with coreData fetches `[request setFetchLimit:5];`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The fastest solution in terms of execution time seems to be an
explicit loop which adds matching elements until the limit is reached:

```
extension Sequence {
    public func filter(where isIncluded: (Iterator.Element) -> Bool, limit: Int) -> [Iterator.Element] {
        var result : [Iterator.Element] = []
        result.reserveCapacity(limit)
        var count = 0
        var it = makeIterator()

        // While limit not reached and there are more elements ...
        while count < limit, let element = it.next() {
            if isIncluded(element) {
                result.append(element)
                count += 1
            }
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
let numbers = Array(0 ..< 2000)
let result = numbers.filter(where: { $0 % 3 == 0 }, limit: 5)
print(result) // [0, 3, 6, 9, 12]
```

Comment: Another tribute to the explicit loops, neat! :) A corner case, but you might want to consider reserving a capacity that is the minimum of `limit` and the `underestimatedCount` of the sequence (e.g. `result.reserveCapacity(Swift.min(limit, underestimatedCount))`) in case a user (misusably) calls this with a huge limit on a much smaller-sized sequence.

Comment: @dfri: I am not sure if that is better. `underestimatedCount` is zero for all sequences whose length is not a-priori known, so that would work only for arrays or other `RandomAccessCollection`s.

Comment: Ah yes, of course. Then maybe only in the case the extension where to be made to `Collection` rather than `Sequence` :) Is there any particular reason for using the more general extension to `Sequence` here rather than `Collection`? (Since we return a type that is more-specific as a `Collection` and not just a `Sequence`). Ninja-edit: but then again so does the [std lib `filter` of `Sequence`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Sequence.swift#L846) ...

Answer (score 7):

You can use `.lazy` too boost the performance a bit:

```
let numbers: [Int] = Array(0 ..< 2000)

let result: AnySequence = numbers
    .lazy
    .filter {
        print("Calling filter for: \($0)")
        return ($0 % 3) == 0
    }
    .prefix(5)

print(Array(result))
```

This will call the `filter` function only for the first 15 values (until it finds 5 that pass the filter).

Now you can concentrate on boosting the performance of the `filter` itself. E.g. by caching values. You don't have to do this but if some values keep repeating, it can boost the performance a lot.

```
let numbers: [Int] = Array(0 ..< 2000)
var filterCache: [Int: Bool] = [:]

let result: AnySequence = numbers
    .lazy
    .filter {
        if let cachedResult = filterCache[$0] {
            return cachedResult
        }

        print("Calling filter for: \($0)")
        let result = (($0 % 3) == 0)

        filterCache[$0] = result

        return result
    }
    .prefix(5)

print(Array(result))
```

You can apply this method directly to your function.

Also note that to boost performance, you should either:

- save `((row.value as? String)?.lowercased())!` into a local variable because it is executed multiple times
- simplify the expression using options:

```
 let result: AnySequence = providerArray
     .lazy
     .filter {
       $0.range(of: row.value as! String, options: [.caseInsensitive]) != nil
     }
     .prefix(5)
```

Comment: whould  that would be a valid filter ? I mean it will apply filter only on first 15 values.

Comment: If you annotate `result` as an `AnySequence`, `filter`'s predicate will only be called once per element (then you can do away with the caching). This is because `prefix(_:)` by default it outputs a slice, which first requires indexing of the lazy collection, which has to run through the filter, and then again for the `Array(_:)` initialiser. Although why it's being run through for a 3rd time, I'm not too sure.

Comment: @Hamish I think the conversion to `Array` currently does. But you are right. Declaring `AnySequence` did reduce the 3 calls to 1.

Comment: Even `print(results.first!)` traverses through indices 0...15, 0...3 before printing the first element. @Hamish apparently has the explanation, but the behavior  might be unexpected, and the solution is not obvious (at least not to me). – Btw, `let result = numbers.makeIterator().lazy.filter ...` works as well.

Comment: @MartinR Yeah, that's because `prefix(5)` (in the case of outputting a slice) needs to advance the index up to the 5th element in the filtered result, thus going through indices 0...15. `first` then has to traverse 0...3 to find the first from the filtered result :) I am planning on looking into this more later today and might post a Q&A explaining it out in detail, as I agree that this behaviour is not at all obvious.

Comment: I went ahead and [posted a Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41940243/2976878) explaining this behaviour.