# Count the number of nil values in arrary of Int Optionals

Tags: arrays, swift

I'm just starting out with Swift and working with optionals. Struggling to count the number of nils in a test array after using generateRandomArrayOfIntsAndNils()

This is the approach I'm going for:

```
let array1: [Int?]
array1 = generateRandomArrayOfIntsAndNils()\

var total = 0

for i in array1 {
    if(array1[i] == nil){
    total += 1
    }
}

print(total)
```

Any recommendations or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: thank you for the responses everyone!

Comment: If an answer helped you, you should mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 10):

You could do:

```
let countNils = array1.filter({ $0 == nil }).count
```

Answer (score 4):

## Counting number of `nil` values

#### Using `for case ...`

In addition to the functional approaches already mentioned, you could use a `for case ... in` loop for conditionally incrementing the `total` counter

```
let arr = [1, nil, 3, 4, nil, 6] // [Int?] inferred

var numberOfNilValues = 0
for case .none in arr { numberOfNilValues += 1 }
print(numberOfNilValues) // 2
```

#### Using `for ... where`

Or, alternatively, a `for` loop coupled with a `where` clause for the conditional incrementation:

```
let arr = [1, nil, 3, 4, nil, 6]

var numberOfNilValues = 0
for e in arr where e == nil { numberOfNilValues += 1 }
print(numberOfNilValues) // 2
```

---

## Counting number of non-`nil` values

It might also be worth explicitly mentioning that we can similarly use the `for case ...` approach from above to count the number of values that *are not* `nil` (namely, that are `.some`):

```
let arr = [1, nil, 3, 4, nil, 6]

var numberOfNonNilValues = 0
for case .some in arr { numberOfNonNilValues += 1 }
print(numberOfNonNilValues) // 4
```

For this case, we may also use the shorthand (wildcard optional pattern) `_?` form:

```
var numberOfNonNilValues = 0
for case _? in arr { numberOfNonNilValues += 1 }
print(numberOfNonNilValues) // 4
```

Comment: Clever use of the language features: `for case` and `for ... where`

Comment: Now I can return your comment [Another tribute to the explicit loops](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41871861/limit-the-results-of-a-swift-array-filter-to-x-for-performance/41873580#comment70929185_41873580) :) – These seems to be the fastest solutions of all posted so far.

Comment: @MartinR hehe, thanks; we keep returning to the good old' (tweaked) explicit loops :) ah, I didn't benchmarks them myself, but I suspected the `reduce` and explicit loop approaches would be faster; curious that `reduce` isn't comparable to the ones above for release mode, but maybe the compiler isn't quite there yet.

Answer (score 2):

More efficient since it doesn't have to create an intermidiary array holding all the `nil`s:

```
let array1: [Int?] = [1,2,3,nil,nil]
let nilCount = array1.reduce(0) { $0 + ($1 == nil ? 1 : 0) }

print(nilCount) // 2
```

How it works:

- `reduce` starts with an initial value and iterate through each element on the array
- We start the count at 0
- If the element is nil, add 1 to the running total (`$0` is the running total, `$1` is the current element)

Comment: And a silly alternative: `let nilCount = array1.reduce(0) { $0 + ($1.map { _ in 0 } ?? 1) }` :)

Comment: @dfri Why not directly `array.lazy.map { $0 == nil ? 1 : 0 }.reduce(0, +)`?

Comment: @Sulthan the alternative in my comment above simply folds over the array in the same manner as the method in this answer, but using a (silly) optional `map` call rather than the ternary operator for the conditional increase.

Comment: @Sulthan that defeats the "efficient" claim of the answer by constructing an intermediary array

Comment: @dfri We can probably think of other alternatives that are more silly :)

Comment: @Sulthan yes indeed :D

Comment: @dfri `NSCountedSet(array: array1).count(for: nil as Int?)` comes to mind!

Answer (score 0):

next solution for the silly solution contest :)

explanation `flatMap` removes the nil values :

```
let arr = [1, nil, 3, 4, nil, 6]

print(arr.count - arr.flatMap{$0}.count 
// 2
```