# Re-write in a more Swift-friendly way

Tags: arrays, swift

Given an array of optional integers, I count the values which are not nil, up to (and including) a given index. I wrote the code down below. Is there another way to get the same result? A more Swift-friendly way?

Here is my code:

```
func getValuesCount(upTo index: Int, in values: [Int?]) -> Int {
  return values[0 ... index].filter { value in return value != nil }.count
}
```

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @danronmoon, the question needs work before it's suited to [codereview.se]. You should have pointed the asker at [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778), as some things are done differently over there - e.g. we need a good description of the *purpose* of the code to give context, and question titles should simply say what the code *does* (the question is always, "_How can I improve this?_").  It's important that the code works correctly; include the unit tests if possible.

Comment: Compare https://stackoverflow.com/q/41881127/1187415

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One slightly more streamlined approach would be to use `compactMap` instead of explicitly checking values for `nil`. And `prefix` can be used to get the first n values, even if the passed in index if larger than the array. And the `return` is optional when there’s a one line result of the proper type.

```
func getValuesCount(upTo index: Int, in values: [Int?]) -> Int {
    values.prefix(index).compactMap { $0 }.count
}
```

With the parameter name `upTo` it implies that the range should be `..<index` instead of `...index`. So the use of `prefix(index)` is similar to using `..<index`. If you want to include `index` then you probably want `prefix(index + 1)`.

Comment: Swift Array has a function prefix which can replace your range. I believe using the range like this it will cause an exception if the range is larger than the array. Prefix will not.

Comment: @Fogmeister Thanks. I knew there was something but I kept thinking is was something like `first`. Edited to use `prefix`.

Comment: You don't need an explicit return on this one, as it's a one-liner. `values.prefix(index).compactMap { $0 }.count` is sufficient.

Comment: @Adrian Another good catch. Edited. It’s just like not needing it inside the compactMap closure.