# Why does filter(_:)’s predicate get called so many times when evaluating it lazily?

Tags: swift

I saw [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41872060/2976878) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41871861/2976878), which, in it’s first revision, had code similar to this:

```
let numbers = Array(0 ..< 50)

let result = numbers.lazy
    .filter {
        // gets called 2-3x per element in the range (0...15)!
        print("Calling filter for: \($0)")
        return $0 % 3 == 0
    }
    .prefix(5)

print(Array(result)) // [0, 3, 6, 9, 12]
```

Which, through the use of a lazy filter collection, is able to filter the first 5 elements of `numbers` that satisfy a given predicate (in this case, being divisible by 3), without having to evaluate *every* element in the `numbers` array.

However, the answer then remarked that `filter(_:)`’s predicate could be called multiple times per element (3 times for elements in the range 1...15, and twice for 0 as it turns out).

What’s the reason for this inefficiency in the lazy evaluation of this filter? Is there any way to avoid the evaluation of the same element multiple times?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

#### The Problems

The first culprit here is the *slicing* of the lazy filter collection through the use of `prefix(_:)` – which, in this case, returns a `BidirectionalSlice` of the `LazyFilterBidirectionalCollection`.

In general, the slicing of a `Collection` entails the storing of the base collection, along with the range of indices that are valid for the slice to ‘view’. Therefore, in order to create a slice of a `LazyFilterBidirectionalCollection` to view the first 5 elements, the range of indices stored must be `startIndex ..< indexAfterTheFifthElement`.

In order to get `indexAfterTheFifthElement`, the `LazyFilterBidirectionalCollection` must iterate through the base collection (`numbers`) in order to find the *6th* element that meets the predicate (you can see [the exact implementation of the indexing here](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Filter.swift.gyb#L231)).

Therefore all the elements in the range 0...15 from the above example need to be checked against the predicate simply in order to create a slice of the lazy filter collection.

The second culprit is `Array`’s `init(_:)`, which accepts a `Sequence` of elements of the same type as the array’s `Element` type. [The implementation of this initialiser](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Arrays.swift.gyb#L1034) calls `_copyToContiguousArray()` on the sequence, which, for most sequences, [forwards the call to this function](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/ContiguousArrayBuffer.swift#L524):

```
internal func _copySequenceToContiguousArray<S : Sequence>
                                    (_ source: S) -> ContiguousArray<S.Iterator.Element> {

  let initialCapacity = source.underestimatedCount // <- problem here

  var builder =
    _UnsafePartiallyInitializedContiguousArrayBuffer<S.Iterator.Element>(
      initialCapacity: initialCapacity)

  var iterator = source.makeIterator()

  // FIXME(performance): use _copyContents(initializing:).
  // Add elements up to the initial capacity without checking for regrowth.
  for _ in 0..<initialCapacity {
    builder.addWithExistingCapacity(iterator.next()!)
  }

  // Add remaining elements, if any.
  while let element = iterator.next() {
    builder.add(element)
  }

  return builder.finish()
}
```

The problem here is `underestimatedCount`. For plain sequences, this just has a default implementation that returns 0 – however, for collections, it has a default implementation which gets the `count` of the collection (I go into this [in more detail here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40152826/2976878)).

The default implementation for the `count` of a `Collection` (which `BidirectionalSlice` will use here) is simply:

```
public var count: IndexDistance {
    return distance(from: startIndex, to: endIndex)
}
```

Which, for our slice, will walk through the indices up to `indexAfterTheFifthElement`, thus re-evaluating the elements in the range 0...15, again.

Finally, an iterator of the slice is made, and is iterated through, adding each element in the sequence to the new array’s buffer. For a `BidirectionalSlice`, this will use an `IndexingIterator`, which simply works by advancing indices and outputting the element for each index.

The reason why *this* walk over the indices doesn’t re-evaluate the elements up to the first element of the result (note in the question’s example, 0 is evaluated one time less) is due to the fact that it doesn’t directly access the `startIndex` of the `LazyFilterBidirectionalCollection`, which [has to evaluate all elements up to the first element in the result](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Filter.swift.gyb#L207). Instead, the iterator can work from the start index of the slice itself.

---

#### The Solution

The simple solution is to avoid slicing the lazy filter collection in order to get its prefix, but instead apply the prefixing lazily.

There are actually two implementations of `prefix(_:)`. One is [provided by `Collection`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/collection/1641714-prefix), and returns a `SubSequence` (which is some form of slice for most standard library collections).

The other is [provided by `Sequence`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/sequence/1641774-prefix), that returns an `AnySequence` – which, under the hood uses a base sequence of [`_PrefixSequence`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Sequence.swift#L693), which simply takes an iterator and allows iteration through it until a given number of elements have been iterated over – then just stops returning elements.

For lazy collections, this implementation of `prefix(_:)` is great, as it doesn’t require any indexing – it just lazily applies the prefixing.

Therefore, if you say:

```
let result : AnySequence = numbers.lazy
    .filter {
        // gets called 1x per element :)
        print("Calling filter for: \($0)")
        return $0 % 3 == 0
    }
    .prefix(5)
```

The elements of `numbers` (up to the 5th match) will only be evaluated once by `filter(_:)`’s predicate when passed to `Array`'s initialiser, as you’re forcing Swift to use `Sequence`’s default implementation of `prefix(_:)`.

The foolproof way of preventing *all* indexing operations on a given lazy filter collection is to simply use a lazy filter *sequence* instead – this can be done by just wrapping the collection you wish to perform lazy operations on in an `AnySequence`:

```
let numbers = Array(0 ..< 50)

let result = AnySequence(numbers).lazy
    .filter {
        // gets called 1x per element :)
        print("Calling filter for: \($0)")
        return $0 % 3 == 0
    }
    .dropFirst(5) // neither of these will do indexing,
    .prefix(5)    // but instead return a lazily evaluated AnySequence.


print(Array(result)) // [15, 18, 21, 24, 27]
```

However note that for bidirectional collections, this may have an adverse effect for operations on the *end* of the collection – as then the entire sequence will have to be iterated through in order to reach the end.

For such operations as `suffix(_:)` and `dropLast(_:)`, it may well be more efficient to work with a lazy collection over a sequence (at least for small inputs), as they can simply index from the end of the collection.

Although, as with all performance related concerns, you should first check to see if this is even a problem in the first place, and then secondly run your own tests to see which method is better for your implementation.

---

#### Conclusion (TL;DR)

So, after all of that – the lesson to learn here is that you should be wary of the fact that slicing a lazy filter collection can re-evaluate every element of the base collection up to the end index which the slice can ‘view’.

Often it’s more desirable to treat a lazy filter collection as a *sequence* instead, which cannot be indexed, therefore meaning that lazy operations cannot evaluate any elements (doing so would risk destructively iterating over them) until an eager operation happens.

However, you should then be wary of the fact that you’re potentially sacrificing being able to index the collection from the end, which is important for operations such as `suffix(_:)`.

Finally, it’s worth noting that this isn't a problem with lazy views such as `LazyMapCollection`, as their elements don’t depend on the ‘results’ of previous elements – therefore they can be indexed in constant time if their base collection is a `RandomAccessCollection`.

Comment: Could this explain https://stackoverflow.com/q/45842065/1187415 as well?

Comment: @MartinR Don't think so – I certainly can't think of a reason why there isn't a special lazy overload for `prefix(_:)`. I mean, it's already implemented using a lazy `_PrefixSequence` type; all that would need to be done is expose it to the outside world (although it would probably need tweaking to a sequence + iterator pair), and then conform it to `LazySequenceProtocol`, and add an additional overload for lazy sequences such that `prefix(_:)` returns it (just not type erased). And then rinse and repeat for collections :)