# Behaviour of lazy dropLast

Tags: swift, functional-programming, lazy-evaluation

I'm trying to figure out the behaviour of `dropLast` when evaluated lazily (questions in bold):

```
var iterationCount = 0

let sequence = [1, 1, 1].lazy.flatMap { (element: Int) -> [Int] in
  iterationCount += 1
  return [element, 2]
}.dropLast()

print(iterationCount) // 18

_ = sequence.forEach{_ in}

print(iterationCount) // 30
```

**Shouldn't the first call to `print` show `0` and the second call to `print` show `3` since it's lazy?** It shows `18` and `30`[<sup>EXAMPLE</sup>](http://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/599ab0d916355a29f03eb16d).

```
var iterationCount = 0

let sequence = [1, 1, 1].lazy.flatMap { (element: Int) -> [Int] in
  iterationCount += 1
  return [element, 2]
}

print(iterationCount) // 0

_ = sequence.forEach{_ in}

print(iterationCount) // 3
```

When I remove the call to `dropLast` it works as expected[<sup>EXAMPLE</sup>](http://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/599ab13116355a29f03eb16e). **Is `dropLast` the culprit here?**

```
var iterationCount = 0

let sequence = [1, 1, 1].lazy.map { (element: Int) -> [Int] in
  iterationCount += 1
  return [element, 2]
}.dropLast()

print(iterationCount) // 0

_ = sequence.forEach{_ in}

print(iterationCount) // 2
```

But wait, there is more. With `map`, `dropLast` works as expected[<sup>EXAMPLE</sup>](http://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/599ab18916355a29f03eb16f).

**Why is this?**

Comment: Related: [Why does filter(_:)’s predicate get called so many times when evaluating it lazily?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41940243/2976878). `dropLast(_:)` is indeed the culprit, as it performs a slice of the lazy collection, and slices often don't play well with lazy evaluation as they require indexing through the collection, which can evaluate all the elements up to that index potentially multiple times. You don't get any issues with `map(_:)` because you've got a `RandomAccessCollection`; indexing is trivial.

Comment: @Hamish That comments seems complete enough to be a full fledged answer

Comment: @Alexander Funnily enough, I actually started writing up an answer after that comment, but never got round to finishing it. IIRC, there was actually quite a bit more going on which complicated it a bit. Thanks for reminding me to get back to this though! Will try and finish the answer either tonight or tomorrow.