# prefix(_ maxLength:) is type-erased when used with a struct that conforms to LazySequenceProtocol

Tags: swift, functional-programming, lazy-evaluation, swift4

`prefix(_ maxLength:)` returns a type-erased `Sequence` in the following code<sup>[EXAMPLE](http://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/599df10acc04b640deff721f)</sup>:

```
public struct CycleIterator <Base: Sequence>: IteratorProtocol {
  public typealias Element = Base.Element

  private var sequence: Base
  private var iterator: Base.Iterator

  internal init (_ sequence: Base) {
    self.sequence = sequence
    self.iterator = self.sequence.makeIterator()
  }

  public mutating func next () -> Element? {
    var next = self.iterator.next()

    if next == nil {
      self.iterator = self.sequence.makeIterator()
      next = self.iterator.next()
    }

    return next
  }
}

public struct LazyCycleSequence <Base: LazySequenceProtocol>: LazySequenceProtocol {
  public typealias Iterator = CycleIterator<Base>
  public typealias Element = Iterator.Element

  private let base: Base

  internal init (_ base: Base) {
    self.base = base
  }

  public func makeIterator () -> Iterator {
    return Iterator(self.base)
  }
}

public extension LazySequenceProtocol {
  func cycle () -> LazyCycleSequence<Self> {
    return LazyCycleSequence(self)
  }
}

print(type(of: [1, 2, 3].lazy.cycle().prefix(5))) // AnySequence<Int>
```

This would make any subsequent operations eager. I know I can just add another call to `lazy` after `prefix` to get back into lazy land, but that kind of defeats the entire purpose of the `lazy` property; once we're lazy we should stay lazy.

**What could be the reasoning behind this?**

Comment: `prefix(while:)` has a specialization for LazySequenceProtocol, but `prefix(maxLength)` hasn't. I have no idea if that is intended or not.

Comment: This might be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41940243/why-does-filter-s-predicate-get-called-so-many-times-when-evaluating-it-lazi

Comment: Thank you. Bug [filed](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-5754).

Comment: I find your bug report rather opaque. In my opinion, you should add a clear statement of what you think the problem is, similar to the last paragraph of your question here.

Comment: @matt: You're right. I've updated the bug report.

Comment: Excellent, thanks for filing.